# Class Magento\Framework\Mview\TriggerCleaner does not exist on running setup:upgrade error occurs on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, error, setup-upgrade, setup-di-compile

On running setup:upgrade error occurs and setup upgrade not started

```
Class Magento\Framework\Mview\TriggerCleaner does not exist
```

on di:compile this error occur

```
In ClassReader.php line 43:
                                                                         
Class Magento\Framework\Interception\ConfigWriterInterface does not exist
```

Content deploy is working fine.

Any idea how to solve this ?